# how i decode base64 to image?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

a develop a application. in this we take data from server just like name, discription, id and image, all information is show on label. But, image is not show proper.

```
xhr.onload = function(){ Ti.API.info('details onload');

var details = this.responseXML.documentElement;

var name_info = details.getElementsByTagName('game_name');
var disc_info = details.getElementsByTagName('game_desc');
var img_info  = details.getElementsByTagName('game_image');
var g_id_info = details.getElementsByTagName('game_id');
Ti.API.info(curWin.id2);

for(var i=0;i&lt;g_id_info.length;i++){

    var gm_id  = g_id_info.item(i);
    var gm_nam = name_info.item(i);
    var gm_dis = disc_info.item(i);
    var img    = img_info.item(i);
    // 
    var image1 = Ti.Utils.base64decode(img.text);

    Ti.API.info('if '+ gm_id.text );

    if(curWin.id2==gm_id.text){
        Ti.API.log('if ok');
        name_label.text = gm_nam.text;
        disc_label.text = gm_dis.text;
        img_label.backgroundImage = image1;
    };  

};  

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an ImageView, and set the [image property](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.ImageView.image-property.html) with a Blob that contains the decoded datas.

Comment: how i use Blob i don't know about it. plz describe it.

Comment: Blob represents a 'pure' binary object. It's something you must use frequently with Titanium. Chek the maual. http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Blob-object

Answer (score 1):

if, u sure ur data whose come from serve in base64, than

You Just take a imageView and your data (image) whose come from server decode in bitmap or jpg and set in imageView.image. 
I think it's working.... on ur application